# How to change a collection field value with presave

Tags: 8, entities

I'm using field_collection module, and $question is a collection field.

```
$question->value = 'test';
$node_poll->save();
```

The above code works for update this collection field value. Problem is this cannot be used for presave.

```
$question->value = 'test';
//$node_poll->save(); // I removed this since it does not need for a presave.
```

When I use above code for a presave hook. The value did not change.

How to set a value for this collection field with presave with D8?

Comment: You don't want to have a save() in a presave() if you can help it. This can create a recursive loop of saves.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. @lukedekker I did not have a save() when I was using a node presave to trigger it (this field is attached on that node, as you mentioned this will create a recursive loop of saves, so I did not have a save()). The value did not change and nothing happened for the field. What could be wrong?

Comment: btw, if I use a comment presave with the $node->save() to update that filed value which on the node. It works well.